# Setting up internal custom domain in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, internal

Please help on the below use-case.

1. We have an AWS EC2 instance with public IP or load balancer DNS --> public.ip or application.lb.amazonaws.com (where we have a custom web apps running as target)
2. We have another VM instance (e.g.: private.ip) within our Data Center (DC) (where the same web apps is running as source).
3. We need to have a web based communication between these 2 instances but currently its happening through HTTP. We have already handled all connectivity issues and we are able to now communicate between 2 instances.
4. We're accessing the source & target URL's as http://public.ip:31415 or application.lb.amazonaws.com:31416
5. Now we need to convert HTTP URL's in (4) to HTTPS along with a custom domain name. This domain name will not be PUBLIC & it will be resolved only within our office network. E.g Domain name: test.source.apps & test.target.apps
6. We would be making an entry in our local machine /etc/hosts (similar to below) to have this name resolution in (5) works for now in test & for other environments we planned to make an entry in our internal office DNS servers for this name resolution.

Example /etc/hosts:

Target:
test.target.app    public.ip.ec2.server
(or)  test.target.app    application.lb.amazonaws.com

Source: 
test.source.app   data.center.ip

7. We don’t want any paid mode of SSL (like CA or public domain) due to the fact that this URL will be used only by 2 -3  developers and within the office network only. But as part of the security compliance we need to definitely make this a HTTPS URL.
8. Web apps are running in Jetty web server. We've planned to do it using LetsEncrypt + Custom domain.

Can anyone suggest if this possible in AWS & any steps on how to make this change (i.e. creating subdomain that is internal to our host/network & 
using LetsEncrypt SSL)?

Comment: *"This domain name will not be PUBLIC"*  The endpoints are using the Internet, so the domain name being public isn't particularly relevant.  Your endpoints need to be *secure* -- not merely *obscure*.  You can't use Let's Encrypt unless Let's Encrypt can validate your control of the domain, which by definition means it must in some sense be "public."  But in a private environment, you can be your own CA. It's not really clear what specific thing you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for reply Michael. The requirement is just to have things,          1. HTTPS URL using which application communicates                                                                                       2. As mentioned the source is in our DataCenter & the destination is in AWS.  3. Have a custom domain configured rather using AWS ELB URL or AWS public IP.   Could you please help with details on how to configure custom domain in Jetty server & use our own CA for doing this?